# How to map a list of integer into a list of string with extra text in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of integer codes like

```
codes=(10001,10002,10003)
```

I want to use map on the codes and return me a string like following

```
{ "code" : "10001" },{"code" : "10002" },{ "code" : "10003" }
```

I tried with following code:

```
result=map(lambda x: "code: "+ str(x), codes)
print(",".join(e for e in result))
```

But it only returns back this string

```
code: 10001,code: 10002,code: 10003
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: How can it go from 10001 to 1001110?

Comment: If you don't write `{` and `}`, how do you expect it to be in the result?

Comment: `codes` is a tuple, not a list. For the output, it seems like you're actually looking for a list of dicts, not a string, right? BTW `e for e in result` is redundant; just use `result` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like you're trying to turn `codes` into a list that contains dictionaries, if I'm not mistaken.

This will do the trick:

```py
code_dict = list(map(lambda x: {'code':x}, codes))
```

However, you can greatly improve readability by using the following (great suggestion and reminder by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea)):

```
code_dict = [{'code':x} for x in codes]
```

And finally to convert it to a string, you do the following:

```
code_str = ','.join([f'{{ "code": "{str(code)}" }}' for code in codes])
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda))` is ugly and more wordy than necessary. Use a comprehension instead: `[{'code': x} for x in codes]`

Comment: @wjandrea thank you for the suggestion - I will update my answer. However, the OP said, *"I want to use map"*

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry my question was not so clear. The reason I tried map is this piece is part of a UDF I tried to construct a FHIR object. I tried your function, it returned what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a **string** like the one you provided you should write:

```py
','.join([f'{{ "code": "{str(code)}" }}' for code in codes])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
>>> str(list(map(lambda x: dict([x]), zip(["code"] * len(codes), codes)))).strip("[]")

{'code': 10001}, {'code': 10002}, {'code': 10003}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the 2 options below:

```
codes=(10001,10002,10003)

# Option 1
final_string = ''
for code in codes:
    final_string = final_string + f'{{"code": "{code}"}},'
print(final_string)

# Option 2
string_comprehension = ','.join([f'{{"code": "{code}"}}' for code in codes])
print(string_comprehension)
```

And you should have:
{"code": "10001"},{"code": "10002"},{"code": "10003"}